# Maintain number of rows in sections: UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview

I am generating a seat map, that have levels which means sections and seats which means numbers of cells in it, but before that there are numbers of rows that hold number of seats in it. But `UICollectionView` has only sections and cells in it. How to manage with rows. Each section has cells in it but how to show them under rows means each section have number of rows. I manage to display sections and cell but not rows. Please guide for the above.

Thanks in advance.

This is json

```
{
Level1: 
{
row1:
{
1: "on",
2: "on",
3: "on",
4: "on",
5: "on",
6: "on",
7: "on",
8: "on",
9: "on",
10: "on",
attr: {
total: "10",
type: "gold"
 }
 },
 row2: {
 1: "on",
 2: "on",
 3: "on",
 4: "on",
 5: "on",
 6: "on",
 7: "on",
 8: "on",
 9: "on",
 10: "on",
 attr: {
 total: "10",
 type: "gold"
 }
 }
 },
 Level3: {
 row1: {
 1: "on",
 2: "on",
3: "on",
 4: "on",
 5: "on",
6: "on",
 7: "on",
 8: "on",
 9: "on",
10: "on",
attr: {
total: "10",
type: "silver"
}
}
}
}
```

Above json showing levels as number of sections, my question is how to display cells in rows.

[image: This is the way i am doing it is showing 3 levels but showing only one rows cells of each level.]

Methods i am doing is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
NSLog(@"levels count:%d", [arrLevels count]);
return [arrLevels count];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"vals count:%d", [arrSeats count]);
for(int i=0; i<[arrLevels count]; i++)
{
    if(section == i)
    {
        int c;
        NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrSeats objectAtIndex:i]];
        c = [cnt intValue];
        return c;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```